# How can I enable the reports menu in SQL databases

Tags: sql-server

according to this picture the reports menu is disabled.

[image]

how can I enable this menu. I thought that maybe it depends on the version of my SQL server.so this is my SQL server version:

```
Microsoft SQL Server 2016 (RTM) - 13.0.1601.5 (X64) 
Enterprise Edition (64-bit) on Windows 8.1 Pro 6.3 <X64> (Build 9600: )
```

Answer (score 4):

I think it's not because of the version of your DB server but because of the version of your **Management Studio**.

I tried to connect a SQLServer 2016 with a Management Studio 2014, and indeed, the Report feature is disabled (only for databases).

[image]

And then tried with a Management Studio 2016, the Report feature is now available.
[image]

So, try to upgrade your Management Studio to the newest version.

Comment: how can I do that?!

Comment: Just check [Microsoft website](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-in/library/mt238290.aspx)
If you have a version of SSMS older than 2016, you'll have to install the new version rather than upgrading the one you already have.